# Select using System.Linq.Dynamic

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, dynamic-linq

I want to select one field from my database like

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext() )
{
    MyClass x = context.MyTable.Where("Id =@0","O1").Select(" new MyClass(DatabaseField)").Cast<MyClass>().Single();
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string DatabaseField { get; set; }
}
```

but this approach is not working, getting an error 
System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException: ''(' expected'.

Comment: I don't think you can project a select statement like that with dynamic linq.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var selectStatement = "new ( " + DatabaseField + ")";
var filtered = context.MyTable.Select(selectStatement);
```

Comment: already tried, but getting System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to cast the type 'DynamicClass1' to type 'MyClass'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types